# Missing references when compiling with VS code

Tags: bibtex, natbib, editors

I am trying to compile my latex project from the Windows Visual Studio code. Therefore, I installed the LaTeX plugin from the extensions. My project is normally built-in TexMaker, however, I noticed that when I am trying to compile it in VS code I am failing to produce properly the citations. I am receiving the following messages:

> LaTeX Warning: Reference `..' on page 13 undefined on input line 52.
>   Package natbib Warning: Citation`..' on page 15 undefined on input line 20.

I am receiving that error for all my references and citations. What can it be the issue here?

Comment: You have to press the button that activates the extra program that takes care of citations. Maybe texmaker is doing that automatically for you.

Comment: There is an explanation for Biber at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502183/35864, you need to adapt it to run BibTeX instead of Biber for you.

Comment: So I need to do the same modifications as in the case of Kile?

Comment: The link moewe gave you has an answer specially for VSCode.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: I add the recommended JSON I correct the JSON syntax errors. However, my issue is still persisting. Still, I cannot compile the references and receive the same error.

Comment: Still nothing the json file does not work for me. Still I cannot compile the references :(

Comment: I have exactly the same problem